# How is it that a generic function expecting `T: Read` or `T: Write` can accept an argument `&mut T`?

Tags: rust

When a generic function needs a parameter of `T`, why does it work with an argument of `&mut T`?

I was trying to serialize a string to a file, using `serialize_into` and `serialize_from` in the `bincode` crate. The signatures are

```rust
pub fn serialize_into<W, T: ?Sized>(writer: W, value: &T) -> Result<()>
where
    W: std::io::Write,
    T: serde::Serialize
```

and

```rust
pub fn deserialize_from<R, T>(reader: R) -> Result<T>
where
    R: std::io::Read,
    T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned
```

I tried to do the serializaion with `std::BufWriter` and `BufReader` but it seems only to work with a `&mut BufWriter`.

Consider this:

```rust
use bincode;
use std::io::{BufWriter, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let x = String::from("hello");
    let mut f1 = BufWriter::new(File::create("foo.txt").unwrap()); 
    bincode::serialize_into( &mut f1, &x).unwrap();
    let  mut f2 = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    let  y: bincode::Result<String> = bincode::deserialize_from( &mut f2);
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

As I need to write and read more than once, I thought a `&BufWriter` and a `&BufReader` would be needed, but `Write` and `Read` are not implemented for them. However, if `&mut f1` and `&mut f2` are used this compiles. Why can these `&mut W` be used when a `W` is needed in the function signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[All `&mut R` where `R: Read` implement `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-14):

```
impl<R: Read + ?Sized, '_> Read for &'_ mut R
```

The implementations delegate all calls to `**self`, so the compiler works like this:

- `&mut BufReader` is an example of `&mut R where R: Read`
- `&mut R where R: Read` is an example of `R where R: Read`

The only magic involved is the blanket implementation that allows `&mut R` to implement `Read`.

In addition, this rule can be transitively applied, so when you pass `&mut (&mut (&mut (&mut buf_reader)))`, it still compiles and has identical semantics.

The same [applies to `Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-19) and [`Box<dyn Read>` also works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-13).

Note that taking `R: Read` and `W: Write` by value is recommended by the [Rust API Guidelines](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#generic-readerwriter-functions-take-r-read-and-w-write-by-value-c-rw-value).